# Setting a Root in File System Tree in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, tree, filesystems, root

I have a FileSystemTree MX control with DIRECTORY property set to a local directory(contains files and sub-directories).

FileSystemTree shows me all folders and files in the DIRECTORY but as child to the root. The ROOT is not snown as part of the tree(see image bellow)!

http://prntscr.com/5amwea

and finally i would like to set a root as on this picture:

http://prntscr.com/5amx5a

There is a property SHOW ROOT but setting it to TRUE doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance,

Filip.

Comment: i've created a directory ROOT and put all other files/folders in there ...

here is the desired result:

http://prntscr.com/5an8gp
but is there a solution to do this without manually creating a ROOT direcotory???

Comment: Take a look here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html and here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html, it can help you.

Comment: i solved this by setting the DIRECTORY property of my FileSystemTree to the parent directory of the directory i wanted to be shown in the tree.

then i filtered out other folders with FILTERFUNCTION property...

(lets say that the ROOT should be "C://")

http://prntscr.com/5b3idm

(but C:// is not shown as root of the tree, only C:// children are snown)

( ROOT to "MY COMPUTER" and in the FILTERFUNCTION 'remove' all other folders, in this case D://)

http://prntscr.com/5b3kpu